# updating remote tables in postgresql (keeping fks)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am using pgAdmin III at my work and postgresql at work and at the remote hosting server (webfaction). Through Putty I am creating a tunnel for pgAdmin to work with my local and my remote databases. I have a table which primary key is referenced by other tables' keys (as a foreign key).

What is the best way to update that remote table with the values I have on my local table?

What I (unsuccessfully) try to do is 'backup' my local table and then try to 'restore' my remote table with that file. However, pgAdmin III gives me duplicate key value error.

```
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: restoring data for table "main_city"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 1972; 0 17110 TABLE DATA main_city user
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "main_city_pkey"
CONTEXT:  COPY main_city, line 1: "1    London  20  30  4   1"
pg_restore: setting owner and privileges for TABLE DATA main_city
WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 1

Process returned exit code 1.
```

Shall I try another postgresql client? It is a pain if I try to remove all those references and try to update manually. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about pgAdmin but how about adding the data from the file into a temporary table and the updating/inserting it into the original table depending on if rows exist or not?

Comment: you say: _updating/inserting it into the original table depending on if rows exist or not_. But how to do that?

Comment: @xpanta: Using ordinary sql (pseudo-sql!): insert into table select * from temptable where row not in (select rows from table). And for update: update table from temptable join table

Comment: Thanks. This is getting somewhere. You are right. I could use simple sql to update my table. This is feasible. But, is this the best solution to my problem? Shouldn't it be easier? This time is one table, maybe next time is 5 or even 10 tables that might need update. What then?

Comment: @xpanta: Afaik that's as easy as it gets, though I suppose it could be made slightly easier with the right tools, i.e. if you have something that can generate the sql you need to merge one table into another.